# Array out of bounds for some reason

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a program that takes a string of ints from the user and prints out how many positive and negative numbers were included and stops when it reads 0. If only 0 is entered, then it should print "no numbers entered except 0."
Below I included my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Ex4_1
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Enter an integer, the input ends if it is 0 (use commas in between numbers):");
         String str = input.nextLine();
         int x = str.length();
         int positive = 0;
         int negative = 0;
         for(int i = 0; i< x; i++)
         {
             int w = 0;
             String[] num = new String[x];
             num = str.split(",");
             if(d1 > 0)
             { 
                 positive += 1;
             }
             else if(d1 < 0)
             {
                 negative += 1;
             }
             else if(d1 == 0)
             {
                 System.out.println("No numbers entered except 0.");
             }
         }

         System.out.println("The number of positives is " + positive );
         System.out.println("The number of negatives is " + negative);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wait, what?  That `str.length()` will only indicate if they enter a *n* digit number, so...if I enter 9, I'll only have an array of size 1.  You're not parsing any of those numbers at all.

Comment: What would the `d1` variable (in the `if`s) be?

Comment: There's no definition of `d1` in this code. This shouldn't get far enough to produce an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: This array is just dumped without using it: `new String[x]`.

Answer (score -1):

d1 = Integer.parseInt(num[i]);

```
import java.util.Scanner;  
    public class Ex4_1  
    {  
          public static void main(String[]args)  
        {  
             Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);  
             System.out.println("Enter an integer, the input ends if it is 0         (use commas in between numbers):");  
         String str = input.nextLine(); 
 String[] num = new String[x];  
         num = str.split(","); 
         int x = num.length();  
     int positive = 0;  
     int negative = 0;
if(x==1 && num[0]=="0")  
System.out.println("No numbers entered except 0.");  
else {    
     for(int i = 0; i< x; i++)  
     {  
         int w = 0;  
         if(d1 > 0)  
         {   
             positive += 1;  
         }  
         else if(d1 < 0)  
         {  
             negative += 1;  
         }  
         else if(d1 == 0)  
         {  
             break;  
         }  
     }   
     System.out.println("The number of positives is " + positive );  
     System.out.println("The number of negatives is " + negative);  
    }}  
}
```

This should be the correct code according to your problem!